# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm very new to react and trying to build a simple react website using react router dom. The before part is working fine but after i introduce Routes and BrowserRouter into App.js and index.js respectively, it is throwing me the error (attached).[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpgYX.png)

**Before:**

**App.js:**

```
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import Header from './Header';
import { Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <main>
        <Header />
        <Post />
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js:**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**After:**

**App.js:**

```
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import Header from './Header';
import { Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route index element = {
        <main>
        <Header />
        <Post />
      </main>
      }/>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js:**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: It would seem that React is null for some reason. Also, the error in the screenshot is different than that which you refer to in the post. Just make sure you have correctly installed all the project dependencies. If the issue persists, delete the `node_modules` directory and re-run `npm install` and restart the project.

Answer (score -2):

import useref in sources of [Header, Post].
if you want more details, show u r code of Header, Post;